# Where can I find facial detection software, algorithms, etc?

Tags: video, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I'm interested in writing software that depends on being able to identify that there is a face in a picture (or video frame).  It doesn't have to ID the face - so no metrics other than:

- Is there a human face in the picture (or more than one)
- Where, approximately, are the eyes and mouth or nose tip (whatever it keyed on.)

It's popping up in cheap digital cameras now, so I expect there are open source packages that do this, or research that is easy enough to follow when rolling your own.

Comment: You accepted the answer that says "Go Google"? That stifles the discussion a bit, don't you think?

Comment: At the time that I accepted it, it was the best answer, and I always try to select the best answer within a day or two (or once the question has fallen off the front page)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the OpenCV library, here is a link for a [good wiki about it](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

[And here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) you can see a sample program of implementing a face recognition app.

Answer (score 4):

Face Recognition is defined as the problem of matching a given unknown face image to a set of known face images. What you are looking for is Face Detection, google it and you should find plenty.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer but it might help. Eigen-vectors are also used in face recognition: [eigenfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface).