# Looking For Realtime Facial Feature Detection/Extraction Library

Tags: c++, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find facial detection software, algorithms, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189155/where-can-i-find-facial-detection-software-algorithms-etc)

Does anyone have any pointers to a C/C++ library for detecting/extracting key facial features in realtime?

Typical scenario: a subject recites some lines from a play or sings a song and the software - in realtime - records the features.

Thanks in advance,
Doug

Comment: I'll let someone more experienced give a proper answer but in the meantime I know that OpenCV has support for detection of facial features. Here is the documentation: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ , and here is a demonstration: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7UdYzCMKvw. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively cutting edge technology.  When done for movie production, it requires lots of advance setup, multiple cameras, custom software, and serious processing power.

You will not find a stock-library to do this.